# Partially Shifting Average does not affect limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the average
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1} ^n a_i \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} a,
$$
is it true that $\frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1} ^n a_n \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}$ a? I know a sequence has a shift in their index, the limit does not change. However, what about this kind of partial shifts?

---

After reading the hint in the comment: $\frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i = 1} ^n a_i = \frac{n}{n - 1} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1} ^n a_i \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} a$.

Comment: minor remark, you want to write $a_i$ inside the sum...

Comment: Voting to close - the answer is there, little value otherwise